# Interference in electron conductance through e.g. single molecule or semiconductor?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, semiconductor-physics, interference, conductors, diffusion

Imagine attaching electrodes to a complex sample, e.g. a semi-conductor or a single chemical molecule, leading to some electric current.

**Can we decompose this electron flow into local flows?** - like locally attaching amperometer and counting what fraction of electrons flow directly between given two atoms, or some larger parts of the system, **like while analyzing electric circuits**. In other words, can we **imagine electron current as diffusion driven by electric field?** - like explained in basic education.

While the above seems natural and intuitive, it was basically given up a half a century ago due to problems with modelling semiconductors. The issue is that **standard diffusion models lead to to nearly uniform stationary probability distribution**. Hence, attaching electric field we would get electron flow - **wrongly predicting that semiconductor is a conductor**.

In contrast, quantum mechanics predicts strongly **localized (Anderson)** probability distribution, **prisoning the electrons and preventing conductance**. Here are examples of electron density graphs for surface of semiconductor from [2010 Science article](http://www.phy.bme.hu/~zarand/LokalizacioWeb/Yazdani.pdf) ([its slides](http://phome.postech.ac.kr/user/ams/workshop_data/Anthony%20Richardella.pdf)) using tunneling microscope (STM) - having complex localized patterns:

[image]

**This disagreement enforced the quantum view: with interfering waves of electrons.**

However, it turns out that standard diffusion models often only approximate the **[(Jaynes) principle of maximum entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_maximum_entropy): "the probability distribution which best represents the current state of knowledge is the one with largest entropy"**, required by statistical physics models. This approximation is repaired in **[Maximal Entropy Random Walk (MERW)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_Entropy_Random_Walk)**, which turns out to have the missing localization property ([PRL article](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.102.160602)) - leads to stationary probability distribution exactly as predicted by QM: of quantum ground state.

Here is example of evolution of standard random walk (GRW) and MERW on 40x40 lattice with cyclic boundary conditions, which is defected: all but marked vertices (squares) have additional self-loop (degree is 4 or 5):
[image]

So MERW can be seen as some "quantum correction to diffusion models", e.g. [here is a simple semiconductor simulator](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ElectronConductanceModelsUsingMaximalEntropyRandomWalks/). However, it is not QM, it completely ignores interference-like phenomena. But **while complete quantum conductance calculations are usually too expensive for our computers, MERW-based diffusion is relatively accessible, still having some crucial quantum properties** - the question is importance of interference this approximation neglects.

**So can we ask about local electron flows in complex conductance situations?**

**How important is interference in electron conductance?** E.g. through aromatic ring of a molecule? Through graphene?